# How to prove that $P(Z_1 = j| Z_0 = i) = P(Z_{n+1} = j| Z_n = i)?$

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

Currently I am reading this [Markov Chains' notes](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/nprivault/MAS328/MAS328-5.pdf).
At page $112,$ section $4.2$ Transition matrix, I fail to understand how author obtains the following.

> As seen above, the random evolution of a Markov chain $(Z_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is determined
>   by the data of
>   $$P_{i,j} := P(Z_1 = j | Z_0 = i), i, j \in \mathbb{S},$$
>   **which coincides with the probability $P(Z_{n+1} = j | Z_n = i)$** which is independent of $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

I do not understand how author obtains the following equality 
$$P(Z_1 = j| Z_0 = i) = P(Z_{n+1} = j| Z_n = i).$$
I think Markov property might be applied here, but I do not know how.

Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prove this. Many books consider what are called homogeneous Markov chain. For these what you are trying to prove is part of the definition. There are non-homogeneous MC's so Markov property does not imply this property.